# How to move the paddle in pong? Bit.Trip Beat's Growth Boss keeps defeating me

Tags: bit-trip-beat

All my attempts against this four pronged evil menace from space have been met with failure on the score of 8-15. The above is, in a way, one of my best shots against the boss; after my absent-minded first moments, I try and pick up the slack, but eventually I always react that tenth of second too late and *plonk*, I'm closer to failure.

I'm afraid there's not much advice you can give me except "stop sucking," but...

How can I move the paddle in pong... better?

---

**Addendum.** While reading the [TvTropes page about Bit.Trip](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BitTrip)*, I read this:

> [Ascended Glitch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AscendedGlitch): In *BEAT*, hitting the pong ball with the corners of Player 2's paddle will cause the ball to gain way too much momentum and go haywire, making the final boss trivial to beat. When the game was patched, Gaijin specifically didn't fix the bug because it was a "cool advanced technique".

I haven't been able to reproduce this. Is this behaviour present in the PC version?

<sup>***** Clicking through may result in an exponential explosion of tabs and should be done with extreme caution.</sup>

Comment: Tagged spoiler because the _title_ spoils the nature of the boss fight.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Comment: @Weegee PC, with a mouse

Comment: how do you get a player 2 in the first place?

Comment: @Raven ooooh, "player 2". Doah; I completely missed that bit. (Coop is cheating, face the facts!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't chase the dot.

While it seems like the best way to hit the dot right on the extremity (an almost guaranteed score), it just doesn't work. Just place the paddle aiming for that dot (conservatively) and if you don't score right away, keep at it. Eventually you'll hit it on the extremity without even trying and score.

Also, playing in fullscreen helped. Somehow, just having a bigger window helped me react better to the flow of the game once the ball starts moving really quickly.

Finally — it gets easier. The more the boss is segmented, the easier it is to handle. Don't despair!

Answer (score 2):

I had a hell of a time with this boss too, but I think the best advice I can give you is to try to hit the ball as close to the edge of your own paddle as possible, this sends it back at a sharper angle, and since the boss has a fixed movement speed, it's difficult for it to get to it in time.

If you're playing on PC, also make sure that you've **disabled** vsync in the options, that made a huge difference for me, much easier to get my paddle into the right position, for some reason.

Comment: I have disabled vsync, as you suggested last time. It doesn't make a lot of difference for me however.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound really nuts, but have you tried reducing your mouse speed?  A lower mouse speed may help you be more precise with the paddle.

Comment: It's also going to completely screw my muscle memory up with other songs... but maybe for Growth, where I have a lot of trouble anyway, it might make sense.

Comment: True, but it looks to me that you're having troubles precisely hitting the ball, so I think it really would be worth it in this case.